# Cast a projected list using LINQ returns a list of null values?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

When I try to Cast the projected list in the BuildTypes method, I get a list of null values. I have also tried using the .Cast(), but I get an error that some of the properties cannot be cast. I can post the error if it is helpful. Here is my code:

```
public class AuditActionType: EntityValueType
{
}

private List<T> BuildTypes<T>(XDocument xDocument) where T: EntityValueType
{
    var types = 
        (from ty in xDocument.Descendants("RECORD")
         select new
            {
                Id = GenerateGuid(),
                Name = ty.Element("Name").Value,
                EntityStatus = _activeEntityStatus,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                DateModified = DateTime.Now
            } as T).ToList();

    return types;
}
```

So I would call it like this:

```
var auditActorTypes = BuildTypes<AuditActorType>(auditActorTypesXml)
```

I have a ton of types I need to pull from an XML file and didn't want to duplicate code for each type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to cast an anonymous object as type `T`, which cannot be done.  The anonymous type is it's own unique type and in no way related to the `T` passed in.

Instead, you could supply the `new()` constraint on type `T` to mean it needs a default constructor, and then perform a `new T()` instead of creating a new anonymous type:

```
private List<T> BuildTypes<T>(XDocument xDocument) where T: EntityValueType, new()
{
    var types = 
        (from ty in xDocument.Descendants("RECORD")
         select new T()
            {
                Id = GenerateGuid(),
                Name = ty.Element("Name").Value,
                EntityStatus = _activeEntityStatus,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                DateModified = DateTime.Now
            }).ToList();

    return types;
}
```

This is assuming, of course, that `Id`, `Name`, `EntityStatus`, `DateCreated`, and `DateModified` are all properties of the base `EntityValueType`.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it. Might be worth mentioning that `Id` / `Name` / etc needs to exist on `EntityValueType` though.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this with your current code as `new { }` creates an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) which has no relationship with T (it is neither a child, nor is it of type T). What you could do instead is  implement `Id`, `Name`, `EntityStatus`, `DateCreated` and `DateModified` as properties on your `EntityValueType` class and change:

```
private List<T> BuildTypes<T>(XDocument xDocument) where T: EntityValueType
```

To:

```
 private List<T> BuildTypes<T>(XDocument xDocument) where T: EntityValueType, new()
```

Which specifies that any type argument passed to our method must have a parameterless constructor which allows use to actually construct an object of type T generically by changing:

```
select new { ... } as T
```

To:

```
select new T { ... }
```

End result:

```
public class EntityValueType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Change this to the correct type, I was unable to determine the type from your code. 
    public string EntityStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}

public class AuditActionType: EntityValueType
{
}

private List<T> BuildTypes<T>(XDocument xDocument) where T: EntityValueType, new()
{
    return (from ty in xDocument.Descendants("RECORD")
        select new T
            {
                Id = GenerateGuid(),
                Name = ty.Element("Name").Value,
                EntityStatus = _activeEntityStatus,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                DateModified = DateTime.Now
            }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code:

```
private List<T> BuildTypes<T>(XDocument xDocument) where T: EntityValueType, new()
{
    var types = 
        (from ty in xDocument.Descendants("RECORD")
         select new T()
            {
                Id = GenerateGuid(),
                Name = ty.Element("Name").Value,
                EntityStatus = _activeEntityStatus,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                DateModified = DateTime.Now
            }).ToList();

    return types;
}
```

Comment: You need the new() constraint

Comment: @James Michael Hare ,@DDiVita - Yes, i mistaked, thanks for your points.

Comment: @RedHat: No worries, it was a small oversite, I assumed you meant it :-)  I'll +1 ya now.